# Wow64GetThreadContext was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mingw-w64

`Wow64GetThreadContext` is defined in `winbase.h` and I found the definition that header file:

```
#if !defined (__WIDL__) && _WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600
  WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI Wow64GetThreadContext (HANDLE hThread, PWOW64_CONTEXT lpContext);
  WINBASEAPI WINBOOL WINAPI Wow64SetThreadContext (HANDLE hThread, CONST WOW64_CONTEXT *lpContext);
```

However even after including both `windows.h` and `winbase.h` it still says that `Wow64GetThreadContext` is undefined. My compiler is MinGW and I'm using CodeBlocks IDE incase it's relevant.

Comment: I `#define`'d `_WIN32_WINNT` as 0x0600 and it compiled. However, will this affect the behavior of the rest of the program?

Comment: affect the behavior of the rest of the program - no of course

Comment: Setting `_WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0600` makes all APIs that were introduced in Windows Vista/Server 2008 available to your application. If your application uses any of those APIs it will no longer run on older versions of the OS. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yes, setting the version defines might affect other parts of the program. Specifically, if you do sizeof(SOMESTRUCT). In your case you would also be using functions that don't exist on XP so the app would not even start.